# java.io.FileNotFoundException while trying to execute YahooFinance.get operation

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception, yahoo-finance

I have tried to execute the following java code from my android studio.

```
String companyName = "DIS";
Double companyCurrentPrice = getStockCurrentPrice(companyName);
```

```
public static double getStockCurrentPrice(String stock_symbol)
{
    Stock stock;
    BigDecimal price = null;
    try {
        stock = YahooFinance.get(stock_symbol);
        price = stock.getQuote().getPrice();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Symbol Name: " + stock_symbol);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.err.println("Symbol Name: " + stock_symbol);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Double curr_price = price.doubleValue();
    return curr_price;
}
```

The code worked fine until now, and today I get the following exception:

```
Symbol Name: DIS
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=DIS
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at yahoofinance.quotes.query1v7.QuotesRequest.getResult(QuotesRequest.java:74)
at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.getQuotes(YahooFinance.java:381)
at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:98)
at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:82)
at com.markke.stocksinfo.YahooFinanceConnection.getStockCurrentPrice(YahooFinanceConnection.java:25)
at com.markke.stocksinfo.ThreadOfMethod4.perform_method_4(ThreadOfMethod4.java:265)
at com.markke.stocksinfo.ThreadOfMethod4.call(ThreadOfMethod4.java:31)
at com.markke.stocksinfo.ThreadOfMethod4.call(ThreadOfMethod4.java:13)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Any alternative to this case?

Comment: That URL works for me.

Comment: The URL works for me either, but only if I open it directly from the web browser. However, within the code it does not work.

Comment: You may be using a version of Java which doesn’t respect Windows proxy settings.  Try using Java 19.  See https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8262442.

Comment: I have changed to Open JDK 19.0.1 in the gradle settings of android studio. I still has the same exception. Nothing changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @markke Did you find the solution for this? Thank you.